# Relative Layout buttons are not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

Anyone please help me figure out why is the following button1 is not visible in my application?

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AirplaneActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/button_activate" 
        android:onClick="activateAirPlaneMode"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);`, where layout_name is the name of your xml file in layouts (assuming it's an Activity)?

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your XML file so it must be something else.

If you provide more context/code, it may be more helpful.

Comment: OMG, I forgot to call setContentView. Thank you very much